# Edit Options menu item content/settings in android

Tags: java, android, android-menu

I need to edit the value of a MenuItem in my Android application. 
But the problem is that i don't want the item edited inside OnCreateOptionMenu, but i want it edited outside MenuHandling routines.

I tried to use that code but it doesn't work:

```
Menu myMenu = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.optionsmenu);
menuItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.timer);
menuItem.setEnable(false);
```

But it doesn't work the myMenu variable value is null (i added in an id attribute in the Menu xml tag). 
I also tried something like that:

```
Menu myMenu = (Menu) findViewById(R.menu.options);
menuItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.timer);
menuItem.setEnable(false);
```

Same problem. 
I also tried:

```
MenuItem myItem = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.timer);
myItem.setEnabled(false);
```

Same problem myItem is null. Then how i can modify the MenuItem? I know how to id inside the On*OptionsMenu methods. I nedd to do it outside these method.

Thanks in advance for any help/reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` in your activity.

Refer this doc:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu